# What type of regression analysis to use for data on economic experiment

Tags: regression, stata, experiment-design, treatment-effect

I'm currently performing analysis on a dataset I've retrieved by running an economic experiment. Subjects were either in treatment 0 and 1 and had to perform 'real effort' tasks. That is, they had to indicate how many letters they wished to decode for a certain price. This price was determined by a gross value and tax rates. Subjects had to fill in a form with the number of letters they wished to decode under each tax rate ranging from 0 to 100 in increments of 5. For each subject I thus have 21 values corresponding to effort levels (with minimum effort 0 and maximum effort 540). Subjects also had to fill in a questionnaire and had to perform two simple test to measure both risk and inequality aversion.

Now I want to analyse which factors have a significant effect on effort levels, but I'm not sure what type of regression analysis to use. First off, the data as described above can be seen as panel data, right? I've seen other researchers use random effects Tobits, but I don't understand why. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Panel data refers to repeated measures, but usually across months or years. So your data as well as panel data require random effects, but I don't think the term panel data is really adequate here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through the three most important aspects:

**Design**:

Each individual is measured 21 times on the dependent variable, right? That means data are clustered, and you need a random effects aka multilevel aka hierarchical model.

**Independent variables** (IVs):

- Treatment, dichotmous (Is it constant for each person, i.e., a level-2 variable, or does it vary across the 21 trials, i.e., a level-1 variable?)
- Tax rate, continous (a level-1 variable)
- Maybe price and/or gross value are also IVs, I didn't fully understand your design here.

**Dependent variable** (DV):

The dependent variable seems to be normal, so use a standard normal model. Read up on [truncation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_regression_model) and [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censored_regression_model) (-> Tobit), but from my understanding of your data, this does not apply to your situation.

In summary, a standard random effects model with the appropriate predictors seems to be the right model.

Comment: Thanks man, great answer! To give more information about the data: 
- the treatment is a dummy variable which is constant for each person across the trails. 
- People were asked to decode letters for €0,04 per letter. They had to choose under each tax rate between 0 and 100 how many letters they wanted to decode. So if the tax rate was 0% they earned €0,04 per letter , when the tax rate was 50% percent they earned €0,02 per letter, etc. The minimum letters they could decode under each tax rate was 0 and the maximum 540. So is a censored model needed because of this upper bound?

Comment: I see. Well, one could argue that the data are right-censored, because some people would actually decode 600 letters if they could. If you believe this is realistic, and if you observe some 540's in your data, than a censored model may actually be more appropriate. But my hunch is that it's not necessary and would not make a real difference.